# query builder getResult() performance

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig, circular-dependency

(solution at the end of post in edit)

I'm using latest Symfony2, creating small app.

I have this query:

```
$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('first')
        ->select('first')
        ->join('first.second', 'second')
        ->join('second.third', 'third')
        ->where('third.id = :id')
        ->setParameters(array('id' => 1));
$query = $qb->getQuery();
```

when I call

```
$query->getArrayResult();
```

everything works fine.

but when I call

```
$query->getResult();
```

I'm returned blank page and in log I have this error:

> emergency.EMERGENCY: Allowed memory size of 402653184 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 384040960 bytes) {"type":1,"file":"/srv/no/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Debug.php","line":66} []

I have no idea where is the problem, these 3 tables each have less than 100 records (50, 60, 5), query should return only 12 objects and all I do in twig template is dumping these 12 objects...

**EDIT:**

**I found where the problem is, it looks like whole problem is with twig dump() function. it goes to infinite loop (thats why memory goes up) as symfony2 entities are interconnected... so its dumping first->seconds->firsts->seconds... and so on.**

**at least this is my theory because as soon as I stop dumping and just display individual variables everything is fine.**

Comment: are you try to `dump($query->getResult())` or `dump($someobject)`?

Comment: Did you force the `EAGER` loading of your joined entities?

Comment: I'm dumping object returned by getResult()

Comment: and no, I did not forced `EAGER` but I tried it right now and nothing changed.

Comment: Can you post the view and the line where it fails?

Answer (score 1):

You have circular dependency: some of your entities depends on another. It can be bi-directional relation or something else. You can use [`partial` syntax](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#partial-object-syntax) to avoid loading of extra data.

Comment: 'first' and 'second' tables have ManyToMany relation. I have tried to select them using partial, but nothing changes...